# JMS commit on User Transaction

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, jta

so I have this code, where I am using javax.UserTransaction as ut :

```
            ut.begin();
                message = consumeMessage();

                if (message != null) {                      
                    worker.processMessage(message);                 
                    message.acknowledge();
                }
                ut.commit();
```

Is there anyway to prevent message lost on commit failure ? Is there any way to make the commit itself do the ack on the message ? Hope someone can help !

Answer (score 0):

CLosing the issue, you have to use Interposed Client Manager, this will import the transaction to webLogic and then rollback works as expected.